# How to deserialize the data in datapower using xslt which is serialized by dp:serialize extension element

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

Below is the xml input:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Message>Hello</Message>
```

I am serializing above xml using dp:serialize element like below

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="input">
      <dp:serialize select="/" omit-xml-decl="yes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I want to **deserialize** the same data inside anoter xslt.How to proceed with this.

Comment: Hi, that input above does not seem to be correct; that is not valid xml. Can you double check it?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.1.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/parse_element.html there is a corresponding `dp:parse` element so you can do `<dp:parse select="$your-xml-data"/>`.

Comment: First i need to serialize then i need to deserialize the same data.

Comment: And using `<dp:parse select="$input"/>` does parse the serialization? I am afraid I am not a DataPower user so I can't help figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

`dp:parse` is available to you as either an extension element:

```
<xsl:variable name="parsed-nodeset">
    <dp:parse select="xmlstring"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or as an extension function:

```
<xsl:variable name="parsed-nodeset" select="dp:parse(xmlstring)"/>
```

In either case, the `xmlstring` should resolve to an xs:string containing your XML.  Both the element and function versions of dp:parse have an optional parameter that tells DataPower that the string should be treated as a Base64-encoded copy of your XML:

```
<dp:parse select="b64string" encoding="base-64"/>

dp:parse(b64string, 'base-64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input

XML : 
    Hello

Serialize :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="input">
            <dp:serialize select="/" omit-xml-decl="yes"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Deserialize :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="Ouput" select="dp:parse($input)"/>>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```